# SQL Oracle - Group by ID, task ID, min and max timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, gaps-and-islands, match-recognize

I have data of users performing different tasks.
I would like to group this data per userid and task id to get the start and end times per task. When the employee changes to another task, there should be a new row with new start and end time.

Example simplified data set:

| userid | taskid | date_time_stamp (ascending) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | task-A | 16/6/2021 04:17:00 |
| 1 | task-A | 16/6/2021 04:19:00 |
| 1 | task-A | 16/6/2021 04:27:00 |
| 1 | task-B | 16/6/2021 04:31:00 |
| 1 | task-B | 16/6/2021 04:33:00 |
| 1 | task-B | 16/6/2021 04:36:00 |
| 1 | task-A | 16/6/2021 04:42:00 |
| 1 | task-A | 16/6/2021 04:44:00 |

example result

| userid | taskid | first_dtm | last_dtm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | task-A | 16/6/2021 04:17:00 | 16/6/2021 04:27:00 |
| 1 | task-B | 16/6/2021 04:31:00 | 16/6/2021 04:36:00 |
| 1 | task-A | 16/6/2021 04:42:00 | 16/6/2021 04:44:00 |

I understand that I should work with some min() and max() functions combined with a GROUP BY. However, grouping by userid and taskid, will result in only one row for task-A in this example.

Comment: This is common "gaps and islands" task. PS. Either OracleDB or MySQL, not both - select one and edit tags list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY userid
  ORDER BY date_time_stamp
  MEASURES
    FIRST(taskid) AS taskid,
    FIRST(date_time_stamp) AS start_date,
    LAST(date_time_stamp) AS end_date
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( same_task+ )
  DEFINE same_task AS FIRST(taskid) = taskid
)
```

Before that, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and aggregate:

```sql
SELECT userid,
       taskid,
       MIN(date_time_stamp) AS start_date,
       MAX(date_time_stamp) AS end_date
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_time_stamp )
           - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY userid, taskid ORDER BY date_time_stamp )
           AS grp
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY userid, taskid, grp
ORDER BY userid, start_date
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( userid, taskid, date_time_stamp ) AS
SELECT 1, 'task-A', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:17:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'task-A', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:19:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'task-A', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:27:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'task-B', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:31:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'task-B', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:33:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'task-B', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:36:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'task-A', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:42:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'task-A', DATE '2021-06-16' + INTERVAL '04:44:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> | USERID | TASKID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | task-A | 2021-06-16 04:17:00 | 2021-06-16 04:27:00 |
> | 1 | task-B | 2021-06-16 04:31:00 | 2021-06-16 04:36:00 |
> | 1 | task-A | 2021-06-16 04:42:00 | 2021-06-16 04:44:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f4a909a3a5db570e4893faa3566ca6b)*